# Xamarin Visual Studio ios simulator not working

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, ios-simulator

We recently acquired mobile solution that contains an ios and android project. Android project runs fine. When i run the ios project i get error stating [image]

My environment is a windows laptop and a macbook pro running visual studio from windows.

1. I can pair to mac just fine
2. I am using automatic provisioning which appears to be correct since my team shows up in the team dropdown.
3. I feel like i did the provisioning correct because team would not show up in dropdown if not.
4. I have latest xcode installed on mac
5. I verified simulator runs fine on mac by starting through xcode

In the videos i watched as soon as mac was paired then more options appeared besides just simulator. (ipad, tvos, etc)

One question is when i registered my device i used the UUID from the macbook and not UUID of simulator. Could not get straight answer for this.

To be clear i am just trying to run the simulator and not a remote device.

Honestly i just want to be able to test the ios application. It should not be this many steps to just run a test. Is there a more simple way to test or am i on the right track?

Comment: Can you select the specific simulator in the Visual-Studio like iPhone 8, iPhone XS and etc.?

Comment: Jack no i cannot

Comment: I think you should try to repair/update you Visual-Studio.

Comment: Updating visual studio on my windows machine did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating visual studio on my windows machine did the trick. I really wish the error would give me some kind of warning that would lead me to the conclusion that i needed to update visual studio. That would have saved me many hours.

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).